# How to run a function in JS when user hit the reload button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello so i want to know if its possible to run a function using JS by reloading a page.
[image] So what i want to happen is when i hit the reload button a certain function will run. Is this possible?

Comment: Is this not the exact same question that was closed earlier for lack of clarity and detail?

Comment: what is your exact expectation from the refresh ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is possible!

This code will help you...

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "Your data will lost on reloading!!!"; // This will be an alert when you reload page
  // Do Something
};

// or 

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", e => {  });
```

Use to stop reload

```js
// Cancel the event
  e.preventDefault();
```

#### For details :-

MDN :- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Ad